# Load System.IO.Compression.FileSystem with Add-Type throws error

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to extract a zip file using PowerShell. So, I use this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

# some code to download the zip file from FTP #

[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($localpath+"\Test.zip",$localpath)
```

I get error: Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem' could not be found.

I then searched StackOverflow and changed

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
```

to

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll"
```

It says:

```
Error: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFram
ework\v4.6.1\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer
 than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
```

I can actually see this dll in that v4.6.1 path. It is there. What is wrong with my syntax, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your syntax; the problem is that the assembly is not compatible with your version of PowerShell - which is exactly what the second error says. For the first error, PowerShell might simply not have that path as part of the path that it searches for assembly DLLs because they're not compatible (again, see the error for the second attempt, where you specified the correct path for the assembly).

If you can, you might want to consider [updating your PowerShell (and Windows Management Framework)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395). The current version of PowerShell is 5.

Comment: More accurately, Powershell V3 only loads .NET 4.0 while this type is included in .NET 4.5 so yes you need WMF4 to use it.

Comment: Isn't it possible to allow PS3.0 to use .Net 4.5 ?

Comment: No; it was compiled with .NET 4.0, and won't know about anything later. That's why I suggested updating to latest PS and WMF.

Comment: Ok, I ran $PSVersionTable.PSVersion and it said I am on PowerShell 2 Major version. I will update my WMF and see if that helps. Thank you!

Comment: I updated my PowerShell to 5. Now, it throws error on this old statement Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll" . It says that "Error: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\demo\WinSCPnet.dll' or one of its dependenc
ies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)" but I put the dll inside C:\demo folder and its there. Should this syntax be updated too?

Comment: There was a security block on my .dll. I right clicked, went to properties and then Unblocked it. It works fine now. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Powershell version 5+ you can use `Expand-Archive` to unzip files. See this [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive) link.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using `Compress-Archive` which worked on Win10 but not on Win Srv 2012 R2 even thought the syntax was correct and the DLL existed per paths above.

I noticed then that the version of PowerShell on Win10 was 5 and on WinSrv was 4 so I installed Windows Management Framework (WMF) 5.1 which includes and update to PS and then when the ver of PS on WinSrvR2 was also 5, this command then worked.